# How to reduce margins on scrreprt (KOMA-Script) Latex

Tags: margins, koma-script, scrreprt

I am writing my thesis using Latex and I am trying to reduce the right and left margin for my latex document (documenclass scrreprt). I have tried many different configurations of BCOR and DIV commands but nothing seems to work. I would like to have 2cm right and left margins.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,oneside,openright,titlepage,fleqn,
               headinclude,footinclude, DIV=15,BCOR=0pt,        numbers=noenddot,cleardoublepage=empty]{scrreprt}

%BCOR=0pt, DIV=15,
\usepackage{bookman}

%\usepackage[DIV=15,BCOR=0pt]{typearea}

%\areaset[BCOR]{17pt}{27pt}

%\KOMAoptions{BCOR=12mm}
%{scrreprt}

\usepackage{setspace}
\KOMAoptions{DIV=last}

%\usepackage{bookman}

\usepackage[top=1cm,left=1cm,right=1cm,bottom=1cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[square]{natbib}%,sort,comma,numbers
\usepackage{subcaption} 
\usepackage{hyperref} 
\usepackage[ruled,vlined,algochapter,linesnumbered]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{chngpage}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{ccicons} 
\usepackage{xspace} 
\usepackage{booktabs} 
\usepackage[english]{babel}  
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{scrhack} % ignore warnings about deprecated KOMA-Script
%\usepackage{apalike}
\usepackage[printonlyused,smaller,withpage]{acronym}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage[section]{placeins}

\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}

\usepackage{pdfpages}

%\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
%\usepackage{pdfpages}

\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}[2011/08/13]

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}


\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\usepackage{tabularx}

\usepackage[floatperchapter,dottedtoc,eulerchapternumbers,pdfspacing,linedheaders]{classicthesis}
\usepackage{arsclassica}

\usepackage{pdfpages}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}

%---------------------

\input{mysettings}


\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\pagestyle{plain}
```

I hope you can help me.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to set exactly 2 cm margins with KOMA-script internal "engines". You load and use geometry, so use that package instead, since it allows you to set narrow margins, even if it looks awful and is bad typography.

In your code, you set and reset margin using both KOMA-script and geometry, and that will not work. In addition, you loads many packages incompatible with KOMA-script, and several packages not necessary in an MWE. I removed those.

Here is an MWE using geometry. You will have approximately the same left and right margins using `DIV=15`, but of cause, 1 cm top and bottom margins are not possible using KOMA-script DIV-calculation. It is possible to calculate "backwards", setting a weird `typearea` and ignore all the warnings. Since you know the dimension of an a4-page, you know that the typearea will be 17 cm x 27.1 cm. You can then use the command:

```
\areaset{17cm}{27.1cm}
```

instead of the `BCOR=15`. But who wants one centimetre top and bottom margins?

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,oneside,openright,titlepage,fleqn,
               headinclude,footinclude, numbers=noenddot,cleardoublepage=empty]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{bookman}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage[top=1cm,left=2cm,right=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\pagestyle{plain}

\blinddocument

\end{document}
```